# how to insert data in database using cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

i have a table name stores and i have controller name is StoresController.php and model name is Stores.php and have a add.ctp file inside Stores folder but i an unable to insert data from form.here is my add.ctp file

```
<div class="row form-main">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <?php echo $this->Form->create('Store', array('class'=>"contact-
          form")); 
      ?>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
      <?php 
      echo $this->Form->input('name',array('required'=>false,'class'=>"form-
      control",  'placeholder'=>"Enter Name","label"=>false)); 
      ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
     <?php 
     echo $this->Form-
     >input('address1',array('required'=>false,'class'=>"form-control",  
    'placeholder'=>"Enter Address1","label"=>false)); 
     ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn 
              btn-success">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
         <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

here is my StoresController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class StoresController extends AppController {
var $uses = array();
var $component = array("Common");
public $paginate = array();  


public function add(){
    $this->layout = 'user_layout';
    $user_id = $this->UserAuth->getUserId();
    $owner_id = $this->Common->getOwnerId($user_id);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
        $this->Store->create(); 
        if ($this->Store->save($this->request->data)) { 
            $this->Flash->success(__('User has been Added')); 
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add')); 
        } $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.')); 
    } 

}    

}

?>
```

and i am getting error  Call to a member function create() on a non-object in controller

Answer (score 0):

you should be using:

$this->Form->create('Store');

```
public function add(){
    $this->layout = 'user_layout';
    $user_id = $this->UserAuth->getUserId();
    $owner_id = $this->Common->getOwnerId($user_id);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
        $this->Store->create('Store'); 
        if ($this->Store->save($this->request->data)) { 
            $this->Flash->success(__('User has been Added')); 
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add')); 
        } $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.')); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: still i am getting same problem

Comment: Can you show your model. I can see your model name is in plural form where as it should be singular as par cakephp convention.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I solved the problem. There was a minor problem. I forgot the following line in the controller:

```
var $uses = array('Store');
```